# Is this fairly simple looking proposition about sets true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given any family of sets $\mathcal{F}$ is it true that:

$$\bigcup_{S\in \mathcal{F}} \left(S\times S\right)=\left(\bigcup_{S\in \mathcal{F}} S\right)\times \left(\bigcup_{S\in \mathcal{F}} S\right)\implies \left(\bigcup_{S\in \mathcal{F}} S\right)\in \mathcal{F}$$

The converse I can tell is clearly true, however I'm not totally sure about the above.

I might just be not thinking as its early in the morning, and this could be trivially wrong/right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. Take $\mathcal{F} = \Big\{ S_1=\{1,2\},S_2=\{2,3\},S_3=\{3,1\}\Big\}$ and let $$X :=\bigcup_{S\in \mathcal{F}} S = \{1,2,3\}$$ then $X\notin  \mathcal{F}$.
But we have

$$\bigcup_{S\in \mathcal{F}} \left(S\times S\right) = \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(1,3),(3,1),(3,3),(2,3),(3,2),(2,2)\} 
 =X\times X$$

Comment: Ahh I believe it holds if the sets in $\mathcal{F}$ are pairwise disjoint though right? As if $(A\cup B)^2=A^2\cup B^2$ then $A\times B\subseteq A^2\cup B^2\cup B\times A$ but those three sets are pairwise disjoint, thus it must be a subset of one of them. Which in every case implies $A\subseteq B$. Therefore $(A\cup B)=B$. Is this true?

Comment: Sets in $\mathcal{F}$ can't be all pairwise disjoint since otherwise equality can't hold. Say $A,B$ are disjoint. Then there is a pair $(a,b)\in A\times B \subset X\times X$ but then there must be $C$ such that $(a,b)\in C\times C$, so $a,b\in C$ so $A\cap C\ne \emptyset $